# on click toggle - other class width need to toggle

Tags: jquery

On click on a toggle `ID` or `class` - How to toggle the width of other class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-icon').click(function(){ 
        $('.navtext,.prom_arrow').toggle(
            function() {
                $('.iconWrap').addclass('iconWrap1');
            },
            function(){
                $('.iconWrap').removeClass('iconWrap1');
            }
        );
        $("span",this).toggleClass("sprite-collapse sprite-expand");
    }); 
});
```

In the above code: i want to change the width for 'iconWrap'class on toggle time.

Comment: Even ignoring that [the event handling `.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was removed in v1.9 it doesn't make sense to call it from a click handler, because every time your toggle icon is clicked that will assign more and more toggle event handlers. As for changing the width, can't you set the appropriate widths in your `iconWrap` and `iconWrap1` classes? If not, have you tried the `.width()` or `.css()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#toggle-icon').click( function() {
        var toggleWidth = $("#iconWrap").width() == 300 ? "200px" : "300px";
        $('#iconWrap').animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```